# Problema detectando vocales de una string

Tags: python

Estoy haciendo un programa que sea capaz de devolverme True si dada una string, todos sus elementos son vocales ("aeiouüáéíóúAEIOUÜÁÉÍÓÚ") y en caso contrario devuelva False.

Ejemplo:
result = isvowel("aeouieeÍo") # devuelve True
result = isvowel("Hola mundo") # devuelve False

El problema es que lo que tengo hasta ahora no me funciona para todos los casos posibles y por ello necesitaría ayuda en ver cual es el problema.

```
def isvowel(texto):
    vocales="aeiouüáéíóúAEIOUÜÁÉÍÓÚ"
    for i in range(len(texto)):
        if texto[i] in vocales:
            return True
        else:
            return False
    return True
```

Muchas gracias por cualquier tipo de apreciación!

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes! Por qué dices que no funciona? Con qué datos de prueba tienes un resultado diferente al esperado? Por favor, edita tu pregunta y añade esta información.

Answer (score 1):

Una solución:

```
def isvowel(texto):
    vocales="aeiouüáéíóúAEIOUÜÁÉÍÓÚ"
    for i in range(len(texto)):
        if texto[i] not in vocales:
            return False

    return True
```

La idea es suponer que `texto` cumple la condición. Entonces, si durante la revisión se comprueba que una letra no es vocal, se termina de inmediato y se retorna `False`: no tiene sentido seguir revisando.

Ahora, si el ciclo termina en forma normal, significa que todas las letras son vocales, en cuyo caso se retorna `True`.

**Segunda solución**

Sale más simple hacer un `for letra in texto`:

```
def isvowel(texto):
    vocales="aeiouüáéíóúAEIOUÜÁÉÍÓÚ"
    for letra in texto:
        if letra not in vocales:
            return False

    return True
```

Comment: Además se podría agregar "".join(set(texto)) o simplemente set(texto) para strings donde se repiten mucho las vocales, ejemplo: "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaak"